# making each div fill 1/6th of screen width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to line up 6 `div` elements, side by side across the page. However my code only aligns them to the left. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent flex-parent'>

  <div class='div1 flex-child'></div>
  <div class='div2 flex-child'></div>
  <div class='div3 flex-child'></div>
  <div class='div4 flex-child'></div>
  <div class='div5 flex-child'></div>
  <div class='div6 flex-child'></div>

</div>
```

Comment: width: calc(100%/6)

Comment: @MarlonBerdefy he's trying to achieve this with flexbox not `calc()`.

Comment: your code works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/evy2jzf9/ can you clarify the question how that specific issue happens ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can simply put width: 16.6vw

Answer (score 1):

give flex-grow to 1, flex-shrink to 0 and flex-basic to 0px so all your space is available and each child will take same space so all your six child element will have the same space

```
.flex-child {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent flex-parent'>

  <div class='div1 flex-child'>
  </div>

  <div class='div2 flex-child'>
  </div>

  <div class='div3 flex-child'>
  </div>

  <div class='div4 flex-child'>
  </div>

  <div class='div5 flex-child'>
  </div>

  <div class='div6 flex-child'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: op's code works fine on its own https://jsfiddle.net/evy2jzf9/ . question is actually unclear